# How can I get the screen resolution in R

Tags: windows, r, system, screen, resolution

How can I get screen resolution (height, width) in pixels?

Comment: The more useful question is why; is stuff like tk or other GUI involved?

Comment: @mbq gvisMotionChart needs a width and height of the chart that it produces. So I thought i could change those parameters according to the screen resolution of the user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use commad-line interface to [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)

```
> system("wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight")
ScreenHeight  
900
```

You could capture result with `system`

```
(scr_width <- system("wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth", intern=TRUE))
# [1] "ScreenWidth  \r" "1440         \r" "\r"
(scr_height <- system("wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight", intern=TRUE))
# [1] "ScreenHeight  \r" "900           \r" "\r"
```

With multiple screens, the output is, e.g.,

```
[1] "ScreenWidth  \r" "1600         \r" "1600         \r" ""
```

We want all but the first and last values, converted to numbers

```
as.numeric(c(
  scr_width[-c(1, length(scr_width))], 
  scr_height[-c(1, length(scr_height))]
))
# [1] 1440  900
```

Comment: Error in system("wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth", intern = TRUE) :   'wmic' not found.
Do I have to install something?

Comment: @gd047 wmic is available on Windows Professional Edition (XP/7) for sure. I know it's missing on XP Home, but I don't know it could be installed.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy with JavaScript: you just do

```
window.screen.height
window.screen.width
```

You can call JavaScript from R using the [SpiderMonkey](http://www.omegahat.org/SpiderMonkey/) package from [OmegaHat](http://www.omegahat.org/).

---

You could also [solve this with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544510/how-to-get-the-screen-dpi-in-java), and use the [rJava](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) package to access it.

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
toolkit <- J("java.awt.Toolkit")
default_toolkit <- .jrcall(toolkit, "getDefaultToolkit")
dim <- .jrcall(default_toolkit, "getScreenSize")
height <- .jcall(dim, "D", "getHeight")
width <- .jcall(dim, "D", "getWidth")
```

Comment: Haven't actually tested this myself as I'm struggling to get the package to build.  Will report back once I manage this.

Comment: What's with the downvote?  I know the ideas are only half complete, but they are valid possibilities nonetheless.

Comment: It seems to me that this should be achievable without need for a JVM! Personally I'd just wrap up some Win32 API calls but surely somewhere there is a package that allows you to query hardware information.

Comment: @David: It depends on the usage.  For a Windows only solution, Marek's answer is best.  If it needs to be portable, then using Java is preferable.

Comment: best would be if a portable solution avoiding the heavy weight JVM.

Comment: this solution just gives me an error - says it runs out of memory and then terminates R

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer does not work on Windows 8 and later.

Use this:

`system("wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription,CurrentVerticalResolution,CurrentHorizontalResolution /format:value")`

To get you screen resolution in a vector, you can implement it as:

```
  suppressWarnings(
    current_resolution <- system("wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value", intern = TRUE)  %>%
      strsplit("=") %>%
      unlist() %>%
      as.double()
  )
  current_resolution <- current_resolution[!is.na(current_resolution)]
```

Now you'll have a vector with length 2:

```
> current_resolution
[1] 1920 1080
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can call [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing `SM_CXSCREEN` and `SM_CYSCREEN`. This returns the width/height of the screen of the primary display monitor, in pixels.

```
DWORD dwWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
DWORD dwHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

Comment: I believe that the poster is looking to do this from the R language rather than C++.

Comment: @David Hefferman yes you right, sorry, anyway I found this [link](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/CreateRPackageWithC) maybe help